# Break string with line breaks into HTML paragraphs with PHP

Tags: php, html, string, line-breaks

I'm getting text from my MySQL database which is broken into lines (paragraphs). It's stored in the variable `$post_data['content']`. How do I make it print out with the line breaks?

The code I'm currently using:

```
$post_data['content'] = explode("\n", $post_data['content']);
$post = "<p>" . implode("</p><p>", array_values($post_data['content'])) . "</p>";
```

This doesn't work to the extent I want it to.

If I have text like this in the database:

```
line 1 paragraph 1,
line 2 paragraph 1.

line 3 paragraph 2,
line 4 paragraph 2,
line 5 paragraph 2.
```

The code would display like this (which I **don't** want):

```
<p>line 1 paragraph 1,</p>

<p>line 2 paragraph 1.</p>

<p>line 3 paragraph 2,</p>

<p>line 4 paragraph 2,</p>

<p>line 5 paragraph 2.</p>
```

I want it to group the paragraphs together if there's no white-space between lines (just one line break). Perhaps something with the array after the explode?

Comment: Have you tried `nl2br()` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, replace line breaks with `<br />`:

```
$post = nl2br($post_data['content']);
```

Then replace double `<br />` with closing and opening paragraph tag (the original line break is maintained by `nl2br`, so I use a regular expression, that matches all styles of line breaks):

```
$post = '<p>' . preg_replace('#(<br />[\r\n]+){2}#', '</p><p>', $post) . '</p>';
```

Note that this is XHTML syntax, if you want to have HTML, change the code as follows:

```
$post = nl2br($post_data['content'], false);
$post = '<p>' . preg_replace('#(<br>[\r\n]+){2}#', '</p><p>', $post) . '</p>';
```

**Test:**

```
$post_data['content'] = <<<TXT
line 1 paragraph 1,
line 2 paragraph 1.

line 3 paragraph 2,
line 4 paragraph 2,
line 5 paragraph 2.
TXT;

$post = nl2br($post_data['content'], false);
$post = '<p>' . preg_replace('#(<br>[\r\n]+){2}#', "</p>\n\n<p>", $post) . '</p>';

echo $post;
```

**Test Output:**

```html
<p>line 1 paragraph 1,<br>
line 2 paragraph 1.</p>

<p>line 3 paragraph 2,<br>
line 4 paragraph 2,<br>
line 5 paragraph 2.</p>
```

Comment: Even better with `[\r\n\s]` (it works even with spaces between line jumps)

Answer (score 0):

Without exploding the string.

```
$post = "<p>" . nl2br($post_data['content']) . "</p>";
```

Comment: That just creates one `<p>` with everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$string = 'line 1 paragraph 1,
line 2 paragraph 1.

line 3 paragraph 2,
line 4 paragraph 2,
line 5 paragraph 2.';

echo implode("\n",array_map(function ($v) {
    return sprintf("<p>%s</p>", $v);
}, array_filter(explode("\n", $string))));
```

Comment: This adds even more paragraphs, but the OP wanted less (and line-breaks instead).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, using paragraphs and line-breaks:

```
$post = '';
$paragraphs = explode("\n\n", $post_data['content']);
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $post .= '<p>' . nl2br($paragraph) . '</p>';
}
```

This should yield:

paragraph 1 line 1
paragraph 1 line 2

paragraph 2 line 1