# How to I display the data in text from my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I got a database which has many fields. There is a "description" field which contains a chunk of words. How do I display them in such a way that I can have break line between words from words?

```
$arrDesigns = executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM listing");
for ($countDesigns = 0; $countDesigns < count($arrDesigns); $countDesigns++) {
                    $desc= $arrDesigns[$countDesigns]['description'];

echo $desc;
}
```

For example, the data in this text is "The high performance digital video recorder provides continuous video and audio recording plus alarm handling and motion detection. This means you are never totally alone because the digital video recorder works alongside you as your round-the-clock surveillance partner."

I want a break line at the second sentence of the paragraph to display a not-so-chunky-paragraph to the end user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't save the text in db with html tags manipulating the way you want to show it ?

Comment: oh, i didnt know db can do that. thanks man! just save my trouble! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

You can use the Editor

http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-tinymce-editor-category-description

Or

read it for use of  nl2br();

[Break string with line breaks into HTML paragraphs with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013680/break-string-with-line-breaks-into-html-paragraphs-with-php)